# Solve equations by scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, equation

I have a sequence of constant a, and I want to solve x in the equation as below. But it turned to be some errors. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

a = np.transpose(np.loadtxt('/Desktop/a.txt'))

def fun(x, i):
    return 10.6699144 * np.log(1 + 0.0026245 * 0.5 * a[i] / x) - 10.4659342 * np.log(1 +    0.03242374 * 0.5 * a[i] / (1 - x)) 

solutions = [scipy.optimize.fsolve(fun, x0=0.04, args=(i, ))[0]
            for i in range(len(a))]
np.savetxt('/Desktop/solutions2.txt', solutions)
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Something is up with your data you're reading with the text file. If I were you, I'd doublecheck that the `a` is one-dimensional (in which case, `np.transpose` is a no-op).

Meanwhile, you don't need to loop over the index, just loop over the values:

```
In [16]: def f(x, a):
    return 10.6699144 * np.log(1 + 0.0026245 * 0.5 * a/ x) - 10.4659342 * np.log(1 + 0.03242374 * 0.5*a / (1 - x))   ....: 

In [17]: for a in [5, 6, 7, 8]:
    res = fsolve(f, x0=0.1, args=(a,))                                                                            
    print res, f(res, a)
   ....:     
[ 0.07628813] [ -3.33066907e-16]
[ 0.07629924] [ -2.88657986e-15]
[ 0.07631023] [ -1.55431223e-15]
[ 0.07632111] [ -1.11022302e-15]
```